# Swift: associated type with where constraint

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I want to have `associatedtype` in protocol and a method with `where` to constraint the type of associated type to be the same as the protocol, is it possible?

```
protocol Transformable {
    associatedtype TransformType
    func transform() -> TransformType
}

func repeatTransform<T: Transformable>(_ transformable: T) where T.TransformType: Transformable, T.TransformType == T.Type {
    let t1 = transformable.transform()
    let t2 = t1.transform()
}
```

I got:

> Same-type constraint type 'T.Type' does not conform to required protocol 'Transformable'

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` is already the type, you don't want to do `T.Type` in the constraint.  `T.TransformType: Transformable` is also redundant, so you can remove that.

It should be:

```
func repeatTransform<T: Transformable>(_ transformable: T) where T.TransformType == T
```